# Why does GCC allow private nested template classes/structs to be visible from global template functions?

Tags: c++, templates, private-members

I don't understand why in the following code, I am allowed to create the function `print_private_template` while the compiler complains about `print_private_class`:

```
#include <cstdio>

class A
{
    private:
        template <unsigned T>
        struct B
        {

        };

        struct C
        {

        };

    public:
        template <unsigned T>
        B<T> getAb()
        { 
            return B<T>();
        }

        C getAc()
        { 
            return C();
        }
};

template<unsigned T>
void print_private_template(const A::B<T> &ab)
{
    printf("%d\n", T);
}

void print_private_class(const A::C &ac)
{
    printf("something\n");
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    A a;

    print_private_template(a.getAb<42>());

    print_private_class(a.getAc());

    return 0;
}
```

Is this an expected behaviour? a compiler bug/extension?

Just to be clear, my goal is to make the compiler error on *both* the usage of  `print_private_template` and `print_private_class`.

Comment: both of them trigger compiler error in MSVC2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Comeau](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) does give an error (when you comment out the `print_private_class` function and its call in strict C++03 mode.

> ComeauTest.c(31): error: class template "A::B" (declared at line 7) is inaccessible
>     void print_private_template(const A::B &ab)
>                                          ^
>             detected during instantiation of "print_private_template" based on
>     template argument <42U> at line 45

G++ 4.5 on Windows does not report any error with `-std=c++ -Wall -pedantic` though.

Your class `A::C` and class template `A::B<T>` both have the same visibility as any other normal members. Hence, both `print_private_class` and `print_private_template` require a diagnostic.

> **11.8 Nested classes** [class.access.nest]
>
> **1** A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as any other member. The members of
>   an enclosing class have no special access to members of a nested class; the usual access rules (Clause 11)
>   shall be obeyed.

Comment: I take it I found a compiler bug in GCC then?

Comment: IIRC, GCC 4.5 (the one I am using) is an experimental build. There are bound to be some issues with the implementation quality. But, yes of course, you can go ahead and file this.

Comment: I am using GCC 4.4.3, so I doubt the issue is coming from your unstable build.

Comment: Wow, this seems like a REALLY old bug! I can reproduce this from GCC 3.4 and beyond! GCC 3.3 errors as it should, though.

Comment: Hm. Inner classes have been a pain to work with with most compilers till very recently.  I see you've already filed a bug (http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45775 for others). Hope this gets fixed soon!

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Dirk Gently, GCC doesn't perform access control when instantiating template structs / classes nested in other (template) structs / classes.

One way to work around this is to encapsulate them in a non-template struct:

```
template<int I> class MyTemplate
{
    struct PT
    {
        template<int, typename = void> struct InnerTemplate;
        // ... specialisations here ...
    };
public:
    typedef typename PT::template InnerTemplate<I>::SomeType SomeType;
};
typedef MyTemplate<1>::PT::InnerTemplate<1> ThisWontWork;
```

The last line will fail to compile with the error:

```
error: 'struct MyTemplate<1>::PT' is private within this context
```

I'll grant that this is ugly, especially having to use `PT::template` but it seems to effectively prevent clients from instantiating helper templates they aren't meant to access, so it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

**It got fixed for GCC 11**

Ten years later... and the bug got fixed for GCC 11: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41437#c13 (another point in the dupe pool had been previously linked to by [dirkgently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784652/why-does-gcc-allow-private-nested-template-classes-structs-to-be-visible-from-gl/64985594#64985594)).

A minimal reproduction:

main.cpp

```
class Out {
  protected:
    class In {};
};

template <class C>
void f() { Out::In in; }

int main() {
    f<Out>();
}
```

still compiles in GCC 10.2 with all warnings enabled:

```
g++-10 -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.cpp
```

but fails correctly in `clang++` 10:

```
void f() { Out::In in; }
                ^
main.cpp:3:11: note: declared protected here
    class In {};
          ^
1 error generated
```

The above fails to fail in GCC because `f` is a template function.